# Laravel PHP 403 Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

*Note*: I ended up finding out that the problem was caused by a syntax error on the controller itself.

---

Ok so, I'm using Laravel to develop a platform.
I have a form that allows the user to register a domain. This form is submited through ajax to "[my domain]/thedomains/create". Here is the code that does so:

```
$("#btn_doms_create_submit").click(function (){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/thedomains/create",
        data: { _token : $("input[name=\"_token\"]").val(),
                domain : $("input[name=\"create_dom\"]").val(),
                field_ip : $("input[name=\"create_ip\"]").val(),
                obs : $("textarea[name=\"create_obs\"]").val(),
                active : $("input[name=\"create_active\"]").is(":checked")+"",
                itld : $("input[name=\"create_itld\"]").is(":checked")+"" },
        dataType: 'json',//returned data
        success: function(data){
            if (data["errors"] == "")
            {
                toastr.success(data.message);
                $("#doms_create").modal("hide");
                updateTable();
            }
            else
            {
                var txtError = "";
                for (error in data.errors) {
                    txtError += "<li>" + data.errors[error] + "</li>";
                }
                toastr.warning(data.message + "<ul>" + txtError + "</ul>");

                if (data.errors.domain != null) {
                    $("#div_create_dom").attr("class","form-group has-error");
                }
                if (data.errors.field_ip != null) {
                    $("#div_create_ip").attr("class","form-group has-error");
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The code behind "/thedomains/create" is

```
public function create(Request $request) {
    $return_val = [ "message" => trans("system.dom_succ", ["name" => $request->dom]),
                    "errors" => "" ];

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        "domain" => "required|max:255|url",
        "field_ip" => "max:255"
    ],[
        "domain.required" => trans("system.val_dom_required"),
        "domain.max" => trans("system.val_dom_max"),
        "domain.url" => trans("system.val_dom_url")
    ]);

    if (!$validator->fails()) {
        $dom = new Doms;

        $dom->name = $request->domain;
        $dom->ip = $request->ip;
        $dom->obs = $request->obs;

        if ($request->active == "true")
            $dom->status = true;
        else
            $dom->status = false;

        if ($request->itld == "true")
            $dom->is_top_level_domain = true;
        else
            $dom->is_top_level_domain = false;
    } else {
        $return_val["message"] = trans("system.note_errors");
        $return_val["errors"] = $validator->errors();
    }

    return json_encode($return_val);
}
```

As you can see, I have a validation to verify that all the required data is present and valid, according to the needed standards.
The problem is: When I submit this form with some invalid domain or with no domain at all, the verification occurs naturally, the return is given, etc. But when I have a valid domain, the validation throughs the following error on my browser's (chrome) console:

> GET [my domain]/thedomains/create?_token=2vsOrtkcWGid5Ex2HegtY3Fw2E…aE&domain=http%3A%2F%2Ftecnosece.com&field_ip=&obs=&active=true&itld=false 403 (Forbidden)

Idk why this happens. I've already changed the route from "domains" to "thedomains", thinking there could be some kind of blocking from my host, but that didn't solve the problem.
Any idea of what's happening?

---

Edit:

As requested, here is my routes portion for "/thedomains":

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'thedomains'], function () {
    Route::get("/",function () {
        return view("doms");
    });

    Route::get("/all", "DomsController@getAll");

    Route::post("/get", "DomsController@get");

    Route::get("/create", "DomsController@create");

    Route::post("/edit", "DomsController@edit");

    Route::post("/del", "DomsController@del");

    Route::get("/search", "DomsController@search");

    Route::post("/migrate", "DomsController@migrate");
});
```

Comment: Is there any middleware between the AJAX and `/thedomains/create` ?

Comment: @apokryfos just the auth middleware, as well as a language selection one that I made.